# Spring Data JPA Hibernate ManyToOne Postgres returning null when persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two classes called SeriesDBModel and SermonDBModel; a Series contains many sermons.

in SermonDBModel, I have

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="series_id", nullable = false)
private SeriesDBModel series;
```

in SeriesDBModel, I have

```
@JoinColumn(name="series_id")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
private List<SermonDBModel> sermons = new ArrayList<>();
```

I persist the data with this call (service just wraps standard spring-data-jpa repository),

```
final SeriesDBModel persisted = this.seriesDBService.save(seriesDBModel);
```

it seems to write to the DB fine (db has correct value in seriesId in sermons table), and a SeriesDBModel is returned with SermonDBModels. However, the series field in the returned SermonDBModels is  null.

What is currently happening is that the controller persists the data via the service, then when converting the saved model object back to DTO for sending back to the caller, it fails (in Sermon class) because the relationship on the sermon model objects isn't properly set (i.e, series is null).

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
            value = "/series",
            produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<FBCApiResponse<Series>> create(@RequestBody SeriesDBModel seriesDBModel){

        FBCApiResponse<Series> response;
        if(seriesDBModel.getId() != null && seriesDBService.findById(seriesDBModel.getId()).isPresent()){
            logger.error("Can't create an entity that already exists");

            response = new FBCApiResponse<Series>(null,"Can't create an entity that already exists" );
        }
        else{
            logger.info(String.format("Saving or updating series %s", seriesDBModel));
            final SeriesDBModel persisted = this.seriesDBService.save(seriesDBModel);

            final Series series = new Series(persisted);

            response = new FBCApiResponse<Series>(series, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<FBCApiResponse<Series>>(response, response.getStatusCode());
    }
```

Series DTO:

```
public Series(final SeriesDBModel seriesDBModel){

    this.id = seriesDBModel.getId();
    this.title = seriesDBModel.getTitle();
    this.imageURI = Optional.of(URI.create(seriesDBModel.getImageURL()));

    final List<SermonDBModel> sermonDBModels = seriesDBModel.getSermons();
    this.sermons = (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(sermonDBModels)) ?
            Optional.empty() :
            Optional.of(
                    sermonDBModels.stream()
                        .map(s -> Sermon.fromDBModel(s))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );

    final Stats stats = new Stats(seriesDBModel.getPlays(), seriesDBModel.getLikes(), seriesDBModel.getShares());
    this.stats = Optional.of(stats);

    this.tags = Optional.ofNullable(seriesDBModel.getTags()).map(tagList -> new HashSet<>(tagList));

}
```

Sermon DTO **(currently blowing up with NullpointerException because series is null)**

```
public static Sermon fromDBModel(final SermonDBModel sermonDBModel){
    final int id = sermonDBModel.getId();
    final String title = sermonDBModel.getTitle();
    final String speaker = sermonDBModel.getSpeaker();
    final String series = sermonDBModel.getSeries().getTitle();
    final LocalDate date = sermonDBModel.getDate();
    final String seriesLink = "/series/" + sermonDBModel.getSeries().getId();

    final Optional<URI> mp3URI = Optional.ofNullable(sermonDBModel.getMp3Url()).map(URI::create);
    final Optional<URI> imageURI = Optional.ofNullable(sermonDBModel.getImageUrl()).map(URI::create);
    final Optional<URI> pdfURI = Optional.ofNullable(sermonDBModel.getImageUrl()).map(URI::create);


    final Stats stats = new Stats(sermonDBModel.getPlays(), sermonDBModel.getLikes(), sermonDBModel.getShares());

    final Optional<List<String>> tags = Optional.ofNullable(sermonDBModel.getTags());

    final Optional<Set<String>> tagSet = tags.map(list -> new HashSet(list));

    return new Sermon(id, title, speaker, series, Optional.of(seriesLink), date, mp3URI, imageURI, pdfURI, Optional.of(stats), tagSet);
}
```

**Note, I can "fix" this, by adding one line immediately after the returned Series is persisted. But, that seems like a hack. Why wouldn't hibernate establish this relationship for me?**

```
persisted.getSermons().forEach(sermon -> sermon.setSeries(persisted));
```

Comment: How did you retrieve the `SermonDBModels` ? Could you show us some code

Comment: @JedCua, I updated just now with more contextual code. I just cant figure out why hibernate isnt setting up the relationship properly on the returned sermon objects (many side)

Comment: maybe you can try adding a refresh cascade type: `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)`